# Importing raster files in GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, raster, geopackage

I recently started using the GeoPackage format for vector data and I am very pleased with it. Its documentation mentions that it can also store raster data.

How can those be imported in an existing (or new) GeoPackage using QGIS or other open-source software, and what are its limitations?

Comment: It's images only currently - I think. I.e. you can only have Byte type for the raster bands.  (I believe there's plans to support general raster data, but I can't find the link)

Comment: I would read first http://www.gdal.org/drv_geopackage_raster.html, make some tests and come back with a more focused questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use gdal_translate to convert your raster data set to geopackage you will need to also use gdaladdo to build zoom levels/overviews. You can also convert you folder of XYZ Google tiles to geopackage with tiles2gpkg_parallel.py

Answer (score 1):

Use "Export>Save as" from raster do you want.
Change format type to "Geopackage" and select the path and name of new gpkg file that will be created, and select tha name of Layer.

If you select the existing GPKG, be careful, could will overwrite and your will miss all data store.