# Can I store raster data in a spatialite database (in QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, spatialite, database

This might be a super simple question, but I'm a little confused. I don't know what the best way is to share qgis-projects that have raster-data, vector-data and some applied styling. I figured a database would be a good option. And as a spatialite-database can be shared easily, that might be a good option.
But I don't manage to put a raster into it. I think there is some extension-driver called RasterLite, but I also don't know how this works properly...

Comment: You  may use GeoPackage (SpatiaLite in the background)  which is as OGC standard, to store vector and raster data together.

Comment: See this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246959/importing-raster-files-in-geopackage

Comment: Yes you can. You can use rasterlite for this. https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/rasterlite2.html Although geopackage is the easier option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a geopackage format.

In geopackage you can store vector/raster layers, symbology and the same qgis project (from: project => Save to...)